# C# CsvHelper dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, csvhelper, .net-4.7.2

I have a question about NuGet dependencies of CsvHelper, I am not very familiar with NuGet :
In the past, I used the famous CsvHelper (v2.16.3) in a C# .netframework application.
It was a small *.dll near the *.exe file, very light and making good job.

Now I am developing a new application, and I installed the latest version of CsvHelper (v30.0.1) with the nugget manager.
My problem is that after installation and compilation, there is a huge amount of *.dll (almost 100!) in the bin folder.
My project uses .net framework 4.7.2.
Did I do something wrong or does CsvHelper really need all these dlls just to read and write text?
I feel that some of this .dll should already included in .NetFramework but maybe I am wrong

Has anyone observed this phenomenon as well?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: there is no .NET Framework 4.2.7; what sort of project is it and what options did you compile it with? more recent project templates often include 'common' dependencies that you may be able to cull, and depending on how you compiled/intended the program to run it may have parts of the framework bundled alongside it rather than expecting them to be installed on the machine.

Comment: It sounds like you might have done something wrong. [CsvHelper 30.0.1 seems to only have a handful of dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper#dependencies-body-tab)!

Comment: Also, did you mean .NET Framework 4.7.2? There is no version 4.2.7!

Comment: Sorry, it is indeed 4.7.2

Comment: Are you sure you installed nothing else too?

Comment: This is a Winform project. I have uncheck the checkbox: " Auto-generate binding redirects" in my project and there is less dll now. It is correct?

Answer (score 2):

What I did to solve the problem:

-In the project properties I unchecked the box "Auto-generate binding redirects".

-Rebuild the project, now the number of *.dll in bin folder decreases and corresponds to the dependencies found on the CsvHelper site.

-I check again the box "Auto-generate binding redirects", then I rebuild the project and the number of *.dll remains the same.

Strange. Maybe a Visual Studio bug?

What is the purpose of "Auto-generate binding redirects"?

Thank you.